# Rust, how to slice into a byte array as if it were a float array?

Tags: arrays, rust, casting

I have some byte data stred in a `&[u8]` I know for a fact the data contained in the slice is float data. I want to do the equivalent of `auto float_ptr = (float*)char_ptr;`

I tried:

`let data_silce = &body[buffer_offset..(buffer_offset + buffer_length)] as &[f32];`

But you are not allowed to execute this kind of casting in rust.

Comment: This cannot be done in safe Rust. You can use https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html
Also make sure you get the alignment correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use unsafe Rust to interpret one type of data as if it is another.

You can do:

```
let bytes = &body[buffer_offset..(buffer_offset + buffer_length)];

let len = bytes.len();
let ptr = bytes.as_ptr() as *const f32;
let floats: &[f32] = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len / 4)};
```

Note that this is Undefined Behaviour if any of these are true:

- the size of the original slice is not a multiple of 4 bytes
- the alignment of the slice is not a multiple of 4 bytes

All sequences of 4 bytes are valid `f32`s but, for types without that property, to avoid UB you also need to make sure that all values are valid.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/) library; specifically [`bytemuck::cast_slice()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/fn.cast_slice.html). Underneath, it is just the unsafe conversion that has already been described in other answers, but it uses compile-time (type) and run-time (length and alignment) checks to ensure that *you* don't have to worry about correctly checking the safety conditions.

```rust
let data_slice: &[f32] = bytemuck::cast_slice(
    &body[buffer_offset..(buffer_offset + buffer_length)
];
```

Note that this will panic if the beginning and end of the slice are not aligned to 4 bytes. There is no way to avoid this requirement in Rust — if the data is not aligned, you *must* copy it to a new location that is aligned. (Since your goal is to produce `f32`s, the simplest way to do that while ensuring the alignment would be to iterate with `f32::from_ne_bytes()`, performing the `f32` conversion *and* the copy.)